# Allow user that created entry to modify it only

Tags: php, mysql

I have been googling for some time now with out success primarily because the way i am asking is most probably the wrong way.

**What i want to know**

I have made some PHP scripts that allow users to add data to a table (In a MYSQL datanase) and its displayed on a website, now i am working on the ability to edit and delete the entry however the script i have allow anyone to do this to anyone's entry's.

Now i don't know if there are PHP or Mysql functions that help with this, like i said my goggling has been in vain. So if i could be pointed to a webpage that has this information or better yet an example syntax chunk that will only allow the user that created the entry to modify the entry.

I am assuming there is some type of while or if statement to achieve this.

**Example scenario**

A user comes along adds an entry the entry is given an id can the user be linked to that id so only he can edit it ?.

**Note**

I am adding PHP to a word press site so as for the users login information a word press widget is controlling that however i can see the entries are still put in a database field when I'm strolling threw the databases.

**What i am asking**

Do you know of a webpage/example syntax or tutorial that will show me what i need to know or if ya got enough time explain it to me :).

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Why the entry_id should be linked to the user? Make a column user_id and insert the user's ID, so the entry will be linked to the user.

Comment: You could open a new connection with another MySQL user (can be generated easily in phpMyAdmin) that has the precise rights you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the new entry with the current user's id, where $entry_id is the ID of the new entry

```
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id(); // current user logged into WordPress

mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `user_id`='$current_user_id' WHERE `id`='$entry_id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

**UPDATE:** You could also insert the entry with the user_id at the same time with the rest of the data.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` ([other column names], `user_id`) VALUES ([other values], '$current_user_id')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Check if the current user ID is equivalent to the allowed edit user ID in your database.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`='$entry_id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$allowed_user_edit_id = $data['user_id']; // user id who is allowed to edit

$current_user_id = get_current_user_id(); // current user logged into WordPress

if ($current_user_id == $allowed_user_edit_id) {
    // Your code for editing the entry
}
```

Comment: hey mate, Im getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_user_id() with your syntax do you know why this might be

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running?

Comment: Hey, Im running version 3.5.1 i can call the function using function get_current_user_id(); that gets rid of the error however i just get a blank screen for the page

Comment: I can get it to work now, i was having issues with wordpress. is there a way to automate it apposed to manually adding the id, for example giving the post the same id as the user when posted

Comment: Such as in the INSERT query?